# ImageViewer image loop from json codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I have edited the question as your suggestions but null pointer exception is caught.I used connectionRequest instead of multipartRequest since i dont need to upload(just need to read the value frm json). All my codes below, please have a look.

Edited: exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at userclasses.StateMachine$16.readResponse(StateMachine.java:1834)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:438)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:263)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Code:

```
 @Override
    protected void beforeImgGallery(Form f) {
        int iter = 0;
        GridLayout gr = new GridLayout(1, 1);
        Container grid = new Container(gr);
        gr.setAutoFit(true);
        grid.setScrollableY(true);
        grid.addComponent(new InfiniteProgress());
        f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, grid);

        f.removeAllCommands();
        f.setBackCommand(null);
        createPictureCommand(grid);
    }

    private static boolean animating;
    private Vector<Map<String, Object>> responsesgallery;
    String galleryPhotoUrl;

    private void createPictureCommand(final Container grid) {
        ConnectionRequest mp = new ConnectionRequest(){

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
                results = p.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
                 responsesgallery = (Vector<Map<String, Object>>) results.get("data");
                 //i've kept this for loop in postResponse but same error
                for (int i = 0; i < responsesgallery.size(); i++) {
                //null pointer exception in this line
                    final Button btn = createImageButton(i, grid, imageList.getSize()); 
                    //if i simply create a btn like below, it works
//                  final Button btn = new Button((URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, token, galleryPhotoUrl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL))); 
                    imageList.addImageId(i);
                    grid.addComponent(i, btn);
                    Hashtable hm = (Hashtable) responsesgallery.get(i);
                    String galleryImgId = (String) hm.get("news_id");
                    galleryPhotoUrl = (String) hm.get("photo");
                }
            }
        };
        mp.setUrl("http://capitaleyedevelopment.com/~admin/traffic/api/news/getLatestNews");
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(mp);
    }

    ImageList imageList;

    Button createImageButton(final int imageId, final Container grid, final int offset) {
        final Button btn = new Button(URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, token, galleryPhotoUrl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL));
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                imageList.setSelectedIndex(offset);
                final Container viewerParent = new Container(new LayeredLayout());
                ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(imageList.getItemAt(offset));
                viewerParent.addComponent(viewer);
                Container parent = new Container(new BorderLayout());
                viewerParent.addComponent(parent);
                viewer.setImageList(imageList);
                grid.getParent().replace(grid, viewerParent, CommonTransitions.createSlide(CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, false, 300));
                Display.getInstance().getCurrent().setBackCommand(createBackCommand(viewerParent, grid));
            }
        });
        return btn;
    }

    public static final String SERVER_URL = "http://capitaleyedevelopment.com/~admin/traffic/api/news/getLatestNews";

    class ImageList implements ListModel<Image> {
        private int selection;
        private long[] imageIds;
        private EncodedImage[] images;
        private EventDispatcher listeners = new EventDispatcher();

        public void addImageId(int id) {
            long[] n = new long[imageIds.length + 1];
            EncodedImage[] nImages = new EncodedImage[n.length];
            System.arraycopy(imageIds, 0, n, 0, imageIds.length);
            System.arraycopy(images, 0, nImages, 0, images.length);
            n[imageIds.length] = id;
            imageIds = n;
            images = nImages;
            listeners.fireDataChangeEvent(-1, DataChangedListener.ADDED);
        }

        public long getSelectedImageId() {
            return imageIds[selection];
        }

        public ImageList(long[] images) {
            this.imageIds = images;
            this.images = new EncodedImage[images.length];
        }

        public Image getItemAt(final int index) {
            if (images[index] == null) {
                images[index] = placeholder;
                Util.downloadUrlToStorageInBackground(IMAGE_URL_PREFIX + imageIds[index], "FullImage_" + imageIds[index], new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        try {
                            images[index] = EncodedImage.create(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("FullImage_" + imageIds[index]));
                            listeners.fireDataChangeEvent(index, DataChangedListener.CHANGED);
                        } catch (IOException err) {
                            err.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return images[index];
        }

        public int getSize() {
            return imageIds.length;
        }

        public int getSelectedIndex() {
            return selection;
        }

        public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
            WebServiceProxy.getPhotoLikesAsync(imageIds[selection], new Callback<Integer>() {
                public void onSucess(Integer value) {
                }

                public void onError(Object sender, Throwable err, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                }
            });
            selection = index;
        }

        public void addDataChangedListener(DataChangedListener l) {
            listeners.addListener(l);
        }

        public void removeDataChangedListener(DataChangedListener l) {
            listeners.removeListener(l);
        }

        public void addSelectionListener(SelectionListener l) {
        }

        public void removeSelectionListener(SelectionListener l) {
        }

        public void addItem(Image item) {
        }

        public void removeItem(int index) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added the java tag for syntax highlighting. I'm unsure what's not working for you. The code looks good and you seem to be in the right direction, its unclear what failed?

Comment: yeahh, it works. But I hav hundreds of images from json & I am short of ideas on how to loop through the designated image  in image Viewer, which is clicked by user. In the imageViewer code above, I'm stuck in defaultListModel. For eg one clicks img no.5 in the grid view, then one sud be able to swipe img no 6,7....100 and so on up to img no 4 using imgViewer. I cannot put all the images static like abov, right? So I need to loop the images frm json. Hope u get my problem... Thankyou for the reply...

Answer (score 0):

In the [Photo Share demo](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/build-mobile-ios-apps-in-java-using-codename-one-on-youtube.html) ([that's on github](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/tree/master/PhotoShare)) I demonstrate something pretty similar. I used a custom list model that fetches the images to the `ImageViewer` dynamically.

The interesting bit is this list model where the images are downloaded dynamically as needed:

```
class ImageList implements ListModel<Image> {
    private int selection;
    private long[] imageIds;
    private EncodedImage[] images;
    private EventDispatcher listeners = new EventDispatcher();

    public void addImageId(long id) {
        long[] n = new long[imageIds.length + 1];
        EncodedImage[] nImages = new EncodedImage[n.length];
        System.arraycopy(imageIds, 0, n, 0, imageIds.length);
        System.arraycopy(images, 0, nImages, 0, images.length);
        n[imageIds.length] = id;
        imageIds = n;
        images = nImages;
        listeners.fireDataChangeEvent(-1, DataChangedListener.ADDED);
    }

    public long getSelectedImageId() {
        return imageIds[selection];
    }

    public ImageList(long[] images) {
        this.imageIds = images;
        this.images = new EncodedImage[images.length];
    }

    public Image getItemAt(final int index) {
        if(images[index] == null) {
            images[index] = placeholder;
            Util.downloadUrlToStorageInBackground(IMAGE_URL_PREFIX + imageIds[index], "FullImage_" + imageIds[index], new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    try {
                        images[index] = EncodedImage.create(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("FullImage_" + imageIds[index]));
                        listeners.fireDataChangeEvent(index, DataChangedListener.CHANGED);
                    } catch(IOException err) {
                        err.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
        return images[index];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return imageIds.length;
    }

    public int getSelectedIndex() {
        return selection;
    }

    public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
        WebServiceProxy.getPhotoLikesAsync(imageIds[selection], new Callback<Integer>() {
            public void onSucess(Integer value) {
                if(likeCount != null) {
                    likeCount.setText("" + value);
                    likeCount.getParent().revalidate();
                }
            }

            public void onError(Object sender, Throwable err, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
            }
        });
        selection = index;
    }

    public void addDataChangedListener(DataChangedListener l) {
        listeners.addListener(l);
    }

    public void removeDataChangedListener(DataChangedListener l) {
        listeners.removeListener(l);
    }

    public void addSelectionListener(SelectionListener l) {
    }

    public void removeSelectionListener(SelectionListener l) {
    }

    public void addItem(Image item) {
    }

    public void removeItem(int index) {
    }
}
```

Comment: i am afraid the url u gave in the photoshare doesnt work, so i can not test photoshare demo..

Comment: I just clicked both links and they both worked for me.

Comment: when i tried to log in and click send verification in the photoshare app, it says we experience an error connecting to the server. i opened server url ie env-9666990.j.layershift.co.uk , it says 502 error, ooops! Please check you have correctly entered the environment name and try again. doesn't work in the simulator as well as in devices

Comment: I have edited the codes as you suggested above but there's error. please hav a look

Comment: That's the temporary server I used for the demo, the server itself is contained under the main project and you can deploy it anywhere... But you don't need the server! You already have the JSON and images so using this code as a sample/tutorial should work just fine. The code is pretty simple, it just downloads the images dynamically from a URL and refreshes the `ImageViewer`.

Comment: i hav applied my own json but it gives null pointer exception in createImageButton.. what hav i done wrong?? i have kept all my codes above in the question

Comment: Its hard to tell but I suggest you file a specific question on that with the stack trace of the exception and the line where it points to highlighted. Normally NPE's are pretty easy to track, even more so with the debugger.

Comment: sorry to bother you, i've updated the exception and it occurs in "final Button btn = createImageButton(i, grid, imageList.getSize());"   
i dont understand what is "key" used for and what does addImageId(key) method does?

Comment: Its not good form to update an existing question with something completely different as it makes the original question/answer seem totally unrelated. Please file a new question if you have further issues... You are getting a null pointer exception since imageList is null, you need to initialize it with values. I suggest looking thru the code for the photos demo and seeing how imageList is initialized there.